# Second Order Differential equation help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{cases} 
{y}''+2y({y}')^3=0\\k^2+2(k)^3=0\\k_1=0,~k_2=-\frac{1}{2}\\n=1, \ n=1\\y_h=C_1+C_2e^{-0.5x} \theta
\end{cases}
would this be a correct answer?

Comment: Hi @make2r, it seems you have tried to apply a method that would only be suitable for linear ODEs. Your equation is nonlinear and therefore another approach should be used instead. Also, please try to add some background to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry, but this quite hard to interpretate. As mentioned, maybe try to also comment every line a bit. Also a hi from me!

Comment: @Dmoreno, ok I will try another approach, there is no background I am just given y"+2y(y')^3 to solve it

Comment: In that case, notice that obtaining the solution can be quite fiddly since this is a nonlinear 2nd order ODE. Finding a closed-form solution to such equations is not always guaranteed. Is this a homework of some kind? Have a look at the solution to convince yourself this is not a straightforward problem: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+%2B+2+y+%28y%27%29%5E3+%3D%3D+0

Comment: after some advice I ended up doing it like this https://i.postimg.cc/XNFqzmff/dif.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick to reduce autonomous second order equations to first order, to see if this structure then is more amenable to finding an obvious solution method.

Assuming a non-constant solution, set $y'=u(y)$, that is, use $y$ as new independent parameter. Then by the chain rule $y''=u'(y)y'=u'(y)u(y)$ and inserted you get
$$
uu'+2yu^3=0
$$
which is now visibly separable
$$
-\frac{u'}{u^2}=2y\implies \frac1u=C+y^2
$$
Now replace $u$ again and try to solve the first order equation
$$
y'=\frac1{C+y^2}~~\text{ or }~~\left(C+y^2\right)y'=1.
$$

Comment: ok so (y^3)/3+Cy=x

Comment: Yes. And the complicated expressions in WolframAlpha are the application of the Cardano formula for cubic equations to this one.

Answer (score 0):

$$y''+2yy'^{~3}=0 \Rightarrow y''+2yy' y'^{~2}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{y''}{y'^2}+\frac{dy^2}{dx}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)+\frac{dy^2}{dx}=0~~~~~~(1). $$
Here we have used: $p=y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$.
Integrating (1), we get $$-\frac{1}{p}+y^2=C_1 \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{dy}=y^2-C_1 \Rightarrow x=y^3/3-C_1y+C_2.$$